# Flutter How to pass in documents.length from Firestore in another method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a *method* which takes an `int` value, which is supposed to be the value of the length of an `array` field in a *document* in a *collection* in *Cloud Firestore*.

I'm very new to both Flutter and especially Firestore, and I figure it has something to do with how futures, queries and streams works, but I can't seem to understand it correctly.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```dart
class UserBookmarksSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserBookmarksSectionState createState() => _UserBookmarksSectionState();
}

class _UserBookmarksSectionState extends State<UserBookmarksSection> {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,      
      children: <Widget>[
        HeadlineItem(title: "Your bookmarks"), 
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("brites").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
            return Column(
              children: populateBriteList(snapshot, x, true), //Here I want to pass in the length of the array in firestore into x
            );
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Basically I've tried to create a method which returns a `Future<int>` and tried to pass that, but that didn't work because a `Future<int>` isn't the same type as `int`. That I understand, but the solution is not clear to me.

Comment: in the future be sure to include any code you tried in the question, even if it didn't work. it could help other people find this question, and you're more likely to get an answer

Comment: In this case, I believe snapshot is of type querysnapshot, so you can just say snapshot.documents.length to see how many documents are in the snapshot. It will also help if you specify that you are using a stream builder of a certain type (querysnapshot), by using carrot brackets in the stream builder declaration, so the ide knows what type of data snapshot is.

Comment: @Kris Yeah, but my problem is that inside this stream builder I use the collection "brites", but also want to pass in the array length in another collection, "users" > "bookmarks" > array. Is this possible within the same StreamBuilder?

Comment: ah, I understand now. I updated my answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the relationship between brites and bookmarks- that is, which you expect to change more often. I'm going to assume that the bookmarks isn't changing once the user opens the bookmarks section.

If that is the case you can retrieve the bookmarks length value in initState. You will override the state class's initState() method, and then call an async method which retrieves the value from the database. (init state can't be async itself). Once the value is retrieved, you can then call setState() to update the widget with the value of bookmarks set as an int.

Might look something like this:

```
class UserBookmarksSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserBookmarksSectionState createState() => _UserBookmarksSectionState();
}

class _UserBookmarksSectionState extends State<UserBookmarksSection> {  
  int bookmarksLength;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getBookmarksLength();
  }

  Future<void> getBookmarksLength() async {
    bookmarksLength = await getArrayLength(id);
    setState((){});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(bookmarksLength == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    else return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,      
      children: <Widget>[
        HeadlineItem(title: "Your bookmarks"), 
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("brites").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
            return Column(
              children: populateBriteList(snapshot, bookmarksLength, true), 
            );
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

Future<int> getArrayLength(String documentId) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection('collection').document(documentId).get();
  return snapshot.data['array'].length;
}
```

A more robust solution might be to have a separate class that handles both listening to the stream and retrieving the length of the array, and then combining all of the information you're going to display into some abstract data type which you put into a separate stream you specify that is specifically for the UI to listen to.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually some progress for my app finally. One caveat I noticed however is that when switching to the UserBookmarksSection from another page, it shows a red screen for a brief moment. This is the error: "The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(0)" Any clue to what is happening? :)

Comment: did you include this line: if(bookmarksLength == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();? Basically that says, until that value is retrieved, just show a loading screen. Because when you first build the page the value will not yet have been retrieved, so it will be null.

Comment: Ah, that was it, I just missed that line! A big thank you for taking the time, although I was being a bit unclear at first with the problem.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for following through with it, and good luck in your Flutter / Firebase journey :)

Comment: Thank you, this progress led me to another question (best suited for a new question I thought), which I've created here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467305/flutter-only-create-item-which-documentid-matches-string-in-array-in-firestore)