# Flutter Only create item which documentID matches String in array in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still new to Flutter and Firestore, and have a problem where I basically want to only populate a list with items in the collection `"brites"` if (and only if) the `documentID` also appear as a `String` in an array in *another* Firestore collection called `"users"` > `"bookmarks"` > `array` (containing `Strings` with documentID:s).

I have a hard time knowing where to start, I believe mainly due to my currently vague understanding of Firestore and asynchronous streams and queries. Maybe `where()` or `map()` is the solution, but what that is concrete is over my head currently.

```dart
List<Widget> populateBriteList(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, int x, bool isBookmarksSection) {
  List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();

    BriteShowItem _briteContent(j) {
      return BriteShowItem(
        briteID: snapshot.data.documents[j].documentID,
        imagePath: snapshot.data.documents[j]["imagePath"],
        title: snapshot.data.documents[j]["title"],
        author: snapshot.data.documents[j]["author"],
        published: snapshot.data.documents[j]["published"],
        duration: snapshot.data.documents[j]["duration"],
        isBookmarked: snapshot.data.documents[j]["isBookmarked"],
      );
    }

    if (isBookmarksSection) {
      for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        //Here only list.add briteContent(i) if the "documentID" in passed in 
        //Snapshot ("brites" collection)
        //is equal to a string in "bookmarks" array in "users" collection
        list.add(
          _briteContent(i)
        );
      }
    } else {
      for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        list.add(
          _briteContent(i)
        );
      }
    }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So one thing is that when you are actually building the widgets that depend on some data in firestore, you ultimately already need to have that data. That doesn't mean you can't return a temporary value while you are waiting for a Future to resolve. But, in this case, it looks like you are calling this method once you already have the data. So maybe just pass the array of bookmarks in, also (that said, a method like this with a bunch of arguments is a good indicator that things are getting out of hand and some more structural changes are needed - for example, by splitting up the method depending on the conditions and calling different methods as needed):

```
List<Widget> populateBriteList(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, int x, bool isBookmarksSection, AsyncSnapshot bookmarkSnapshot) {

...

if (isBookmarksSection) {
  for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    if(bookmarkSnapshot.documents.where((document) => condition(document.data)).length > 0){
      list.add(
        _briteContent(i)
      );
    }
  }
```

In this case, 'where(someTest)' is called on an iterable list, (documents), each element is passed into the someTest method, and if the result is true, that element is passed into the list. So if the list is greater than 0, at least one element satisfied that condition.

Comment: I see your point. I have now passed in the AsyncSnapshot usersSnapshot (collection `"users"` > `documents with auto ID` > `"bookmarks[]"`), and the condition I want to check is in theory this, hope this code is somewhat understandeable of what I want to achieve but didn't work: `    
    if (isBookmarksSection) {
      for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        if(usersSnapshot.data.document("cn0bRXgzS8bLWboUoozo").get().data["bookmarks"].contains(britesSnapshot.data.documents[i].documentID)) {
          list.add(
            _briteContent(i)
          );
        }
      }`

Comment: The problem with that code is that get() is async, so you can't use it in an if condition like that. You can either say await and assign it to a variable or .then((result) =>...). But since it is asynchronous, you should perform that query before actually building the widget

Comment: I see. But I thought that when I passed in an `AsyncSnapshot usersSnapshot` that I now had performed that query and is now contained inside `usersSnapshot`. In other words, what is it that I have passed in and basically what does now `usersSnapshot` contain? I thought that it was a static snapshot of documents from _when_ the widget was built that was passed in.